# Image overlapping issue on summernote editor

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, summernote

I getting image overlap issue while upload image to bootstrap summernote editor.I have attached that image. I am using bootstrap summernote v0.5.9 and following configuration as well. Kindly anybody give me solution for this.

```
$('.rich-editor').summernote({
        height: 300, 
        width: "100%",
        minHeight: null,
        maxHeight: null,
        dialogsInBody: true,
        onfocus: function(e) {
            $('body').addClass('overlay-disabled');
        },
        onblur: function(e) {
            $('body').removeClass('overlay-disabled');
        },
         toolbar: [
            ['style', ['style']],
            ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']],
            ['insert', ['table', 'picture', 'video']],
            ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
            ['misc', ['fullscreen', 'codeview', 'help']]
        ],
        airPopover: [
            ['para', ['ul', 'paragraph']],
            ['table', ['table']],
            ['insert', ['link', 'picture']]
        ]
    });
```

[image]